# alias to make a new directory and go to it

Tags: bash, shell, alias, cd-command, mkdir

So here I've created, or at least tried to create an alias for a command that accepts a command-line argument, makes a new directory with that name, and goes to it.

```
alias newfolder='mkdir $2 ; cd "$(history | tail -2 | awk '\''NR == 1'\'' | awk '\''{print $3}'\'')"'
```

The alias created successfully, but when I want to run the command with a command-line argument, I get this error message.

```
username:~/workspace (master) $ newfolder a
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
bash: cd: newfolder='mkdir: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a function, not an alias.  Try:

```
newfolder() { mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1"; }
```

Example:

```
$ pwd
/tmp
$ newfolder dir1/dir2
$ pwd
/tmp/dir1/dir2
```

Notes:

1. The `-p` option to `mkdir` tells it to create missing parent directories if needed.  In the above example, `dir1` did not exist but `mkdir -p dir1/dir2` created both `dir1` and `dir2`.
2. Because we use the shell operator `&&`, the `cd` command will only be performed if the `mkdir` command succeeded.
3. Aliases are useful in very simple cases where a fixed string can be substituted for a word.  Aliases do not process arguments.
4. Because we are using a shell function in place of an alias, we can reference the arguments, such as, in this case, `$1`, according to our needs.